# How can I fetch the length of a character array and put it in an array?

Tags: c

I'm working with my STM32 but since I'm new to c/c++ (coming from c#) i find string operations a bit difficult.

Until now I'm sending serial like this:

```
  strcpy((char*)buf, "Unable set read MCP9808\r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, buf, strlen((char*)buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

But I want to change that to a onliner using `Debug` function that I made. But im getting error `'strlen' from incompatible pointer type`. I want to take inn any string (char array), get its length to set up the buffer and send the data.

```
    int Debug(char arr[])
    {
        int size = strlen(&arr);
        uint8_t buf[size];
    
        strcpy((char*)buf, arr);

        // the above code is the important part...
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, buf, strlen((char*)buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    
        return 1;
    }

    Debug("Hello World!\r\n");
```

Comment: `strlen(&arr)` is the same as `strlen(char**)` . this is definitely not what you want. Use `strlen(arr)`

Comment: Why `uint8_t` if you cast `(char*)buf` all the further code?

Comment: Also read about [why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: @273K i dont know, im just smashing together code from the interwebs without really knowing what im doing here... feel free to suggest optimizations :-)

Comment: You definitely should stop guessing and start from [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
.

Comment: @fk69 with approach like that chances are you will just fry out your stm32.

Comment: Or, for C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: *"I'm new to c/c++"* -- what is this "c/c++" that you speak of? I am familiar with the C language, and the C++ language, but I am not aware of a "C/C++" language (nor of the "C/C++/C#" language that some others think exists). The distinction between C and C++ is rather important when it comes to string processing.

Comment: @273K very dangerous advice. A was banned for 6 months (my ban ended today) because I was posting this link and it was considered unfriendly by the mods

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not need to `strcpy` at all as the *HAL* function is blocking.
2. `int size = strlen(&arr);` `size` should be `size_t` and you need to pass `arr` not `&arr`. `&arr` is giving the address of the local variable `arr` not the reference stored in this variable.
3. `buff` is too short and it has to be one `char` longer to store terminating null character.